# Ruby on Rails Routing passing a variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have this code in my route.

```
get '/custom_page/:name' => 'custom_page#load_content'
```

and in my controller is there any way i could get the value of this :name. Pls help.
If my question is dumb please be sorry. I not so experienced in Rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it by

```
params[:name]
```

I'm not very sure about this but it's worth giving a try